# How to cast char* to uint32_t in C?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, uint32-t

I have an array of char* defined as `char *data_ptr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX"`. Also, I have a write buffer declared as `static uint32_t wr_buff[32]`.

I iteratively extract 4 bytes from the array and put them in a substring of char defined as `char substr[4]`.

What I want to do is put those 4 bytes into the write buffer without changing their value but I firstly need to cast each element of the substring to uint32_t.

I tried the following line but it didn't work:

```
wr_buffer = (uint32_t)substr[0] << 24 | (uint32_t)substr[1] << 16 | (uint32_t)substr[2] << 8 | (uint32_t)substr[3];
```

how can I save those 4 bytes to the uint32_t buffer?

Comment: `wr_buff` is `wr_buffer`? Is it an array or is it a single `uint32_t`? Because you can't assign to an array like `wr_buffer = ...`

Comment: Other than that, the code posted looks ok so the problem is likely elsewhere and we cannot help without more details. Specifically what is "didn't work"? Compiler error, run-time error? Crash? Nothing happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The code moves the bytes, but (perhaps, endianness?) changes the order. Is that on purpose? Otherwise `memcpy` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You over complicated things :

```
char *data_ptr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX";
static uint32_t wr_buff[32];
char *posInEntry ;
char *posInOutput;

posInEntry = data_ptr;
posInOutput = (char *) wr_buff;
while (posInEntry < strlen(data_ptr)) {
    posInOutput[3] = posInEntry++;
    posInOutput[2] = posInEntry++;
    posInOutput[1] = posInEntry++;
    posInOutput[0] = posInEntry++;
    posInOutput += 4;
}
```

Note (thanks to @ user16217248 for pointing out few errors) :

- uint32_t is defined in stdint.h
- strlen is defined in string.h

Comment: Watch the endianness, though.

Comment: `posInEntry < strlen(data_ptr)` is plain wrong. Perhaps you meant `*posInEntry != '\0'`? Use a for loop with an iterator instead.

Comment: @user16217248 : thanks. I corrected the missing ; and ) . This code requires includes of  string.h (strlen ) and math.h (uint32_t)

Comment: @PtitXav `uint32_t` is defined in `stdint.h`, not `math.h`

Comment: @user16217248 : corrected. I am more used to include math.h (on my device it defines uint32_t, may be indirectly)